# Why do the ALPHA channel in TGA is not visible?

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, alpha

Good morning GDSE,

I am loading a TGA using loadTGA function found in superbible 4th edition source code.
Here is how the image looks in Gimp

[image: tga, as seen in Gimp]

You can see I have enabled alpha channel in Gimp, I exported this to TGA image, without RLE compression, and 32bpp. But when I load the image in my OpenGL code, the part of the image which is supposed to be transparent is seen white.

[image: bad tga transparency]

Where I must be going wrong? The type of TGA is set to GL_RGBA, 32 bpp.

Here is my Fragment shader code.

`out_fragColor = (vec4( ambAndDiff, 1 ) * texColor) + vec4(spec,0.0);`

I have calculated ambAndDiff and spec values earlier using ADS phong shading, and both of them are vec3. 
Let me know if you also want to view the TGA loading code. :)

Regards,
A.

Comment: It looks like you haven't enabled alpha blending. Try this:
`glEnable(GL_BLEND);`
`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Comment: Not sure alpha blending is the problem. The Gimp sets the alpha value of fully transparent pixels to black, not white.

Comment: Can you post your glTexImage2D call?

Comment: @Sam Hocevar, I would like to confirm that it is not the alpha blending problem indeed, 

@JimmyShelter, here is my glTexImage2D code.
tgaType, as mentioned about is GL_RGBA.
`    glTexImage2D`
  (
  GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
  0, 
  tgaType, 
  planeTexture.width, 
  planeTexture.height, 
  0, 
  tgaType, 
  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
  planeTexture.imageData
  ); `

Comment: OK, that's correct.  It's most likely blend states, as per Tordin's answer then.

Comment: Ok, I will read more about them, and post if i find the issue :) 

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You have most probably not set the correct blendstates to the gpu.
If you have not, the gpu dont know how to handle your Alpha values.

this [link](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending) is a good resource on how blendstates works. and how you should use them.

Basicly alpha is only anohter channel containing data. the texture itself never states what blendmode will apply or how the gpu will use it. that is all done by code.